# How to not add every library inside Flutter project with Dartdoc

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

When I launch the command `dartdoc --auto-include-dependencies`, how can I do to not create documentation for every single library in the project? I use Melos in my project.

Answer (score 1):

As of [dartdoc 0.35.0](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc/versions/0.35.0) you can define nodoc as option and pass array of path of dart files with wild card ***.dart** in dartdoc_options.yaml.
This will treat those files marked as **///@nodoc**.
Basically saves us writing **///@nodoc** in required files

Example:

```
    dartdoc:

      nodoc: [ 'lib/utils/*.dart','lib/views/**/*.dart','lib/constants/*.dart' ]
```

Download file from [here](https://gist.github.com/abhimortal6/0168e3363282a5f9a842b13b26ccb5c4)

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the documentation of the dartdoc package on pub.dev. Here is the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc).

If you want to exclude single libraries (specific .dart files) you can use the `@nodoc` notation, which will be recognized by the package.
For excluding entire folders you can move them in the directory `lib/src`, then the libraries will not be documented, see [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/2236#issuecomment-644864838).

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, how I can do for don't create documentation about Flutter libraries? like bloc or bloc_test..?

Comment: Why cant you add your bloc files unter src? So you have lib/src/bloc and e.g. lib/src/screens - for tests you could either add the notation, there might be better solutions though. I recommend diving deeper into the package docs

Comment: no sir probably, I can't explain my situation: I have a Melos project and, when I launch the command 'dartdoc --auto-include-dependencies', It generates documentation for every single library (dart:js, dart:core, bloc etc). I want that this, doesn't appear but I don't know how..these libraries aren't mine, so I can't push it under lib/src

Comment: Ah okay. However, I am not familiar with Melos at all sorry.

Comment: maybe I have the solution. I can go inside every single folder and launch dartdoc. maybe it will be useful, what do you think ?

Comment: Oh I see, yeah you should of course run it inside the lib folder, else you include everysingle dart library with your command (and there are a lot ;) ) - Let me know if that works and I will update the answer for future references!

Comment: Well, it is too difficult to do that, because there are too many things to do..so maybe, it's better to create a dartdoc_options.yaml and maybe, you can do the same thing but in a easy way (I think)